# Step function properties!

Tags: step-function

Is there an expression for 
$\theta (x^2-y^2)$ in term of $\theta(x-y)$? Where $\theta(x)$ is step function.

And is $\theta(ax-y)=\theta(x-y/a)$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\theta (xy)~=~\theta (x)\theta (y)+\theta (-x)\theta (-y)$$
[almost everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almost_everywhere). Hence
$$\theta (x^2-y^2)~=~\theta (x-y)\theta (x+y)+\theta (y-x)\theta (-x-y),$$
and
$$\theta (ax-y)~=~\theta (a)\theta (x-y/a)+\theta (-a)\theta (y/a-x), \qquad a~\neq~0.$$